# update forms.FileField on django forms

Tags: django, django-forms, django-file-upload

I have a model with a FileField in it:

```
class DocumentUpload(models.Model):
    document_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    document_path = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads')
```

and a form which uses this model

```
class DocumentUploadForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = DocumentUpload
```

When I use the form to create a new upload everything works fine.

```
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
```

However when I try and update/edit the entry it updates all the fields apart from the document which is uploaded.  This just stays the same as the original upload.

```
d = get_object_or_404(DocumentUpload, pk=id)

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = DocumentUploadForm(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES, instance=d)
    if form.is_valid():
        u = form.save()
```

How do I get it to change the upload file when editing the instance?

Thanks

Comment: Is your form template enctype="multipart/form-data" ?

Comment: That was the problem I Can't believe I missed it. Thanks

Comment: I am digging up an old post, as I am having the same problem. I already have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in my form, so that wouldnt be the solution. HOwever, I am curious about the `data=` what does this refer to in your code? my code is very similar to yours with the exception of this, so I am wondering if this could be the key.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since it was my idea, I'll post it up as an answer (just to stroke my own ego and/or rating)...

Add the following to your form's template:

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

feel free to check it off as an answer...

:)

Comment: There is a typo in "mutlipart".

Answer (score 0):

just needed to add:

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

to my form.  Thanks Brant