# Django image file not getting uploaded

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-admin

models.py

```
class Report(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=False)
    photo_files_attached = models.BooleanField('Photos', default=False)
```

forms.py

```
class MediaForm(forms.ModelForm):
    photo_files_attached = forms.FileField(label='Choose a file')
    class Meta:
        model = Report
        field = ['photo_files_attached']
```

views.py

```
def media(request):
    user = request.user  
    try:
        report = Report.objects.get(user=user.id)
    except:
        report = None
    mediaForm = MediaForm()
    if request.method =='POST':
        mediaForm = MediaForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if mediaForm.is_valid():
            media = Report(photo_files_attached = request.FILES['photo_files_attached'])
            media.save()


    return render(request, 'media.html',
                  {

                   'mediaForm':MediaForm,

                 })
```

I am trying to upload a image file through django and save it in database.Once the file is saved ,the images are get collecetd in media folder in project.But it is completely not working.May i know what i did wrong.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can see you don't have a single `FileField` on your `Model` so where do you expect any uploaded files to be bound to your object?

You should either create your own saving logic in within the `form.is_valid()` scope or use a different approach overall.

Here's a single file example, using a modelform, [update forms.FileField on django forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719662/update-forms-filefield-on-django-forms)

Comment: I am using BooleanField,so that,if a file uploaded and save in database  it should be  saved as '1' if the file is uploaded sucessfully else it should be always '0'.It is actually a small module for me to do,since the db is already designed i con't do any alteration.Any idea how to proceed this further.

Comment: Any idea in which way we can perform,please suggest me,have any reference file please share with me.Thanks

Comment: Why can't you alter the database with a schemamigration tool like [south](http://south.aeracode.org/)?

Comment: You can save the files manually to the filesystem and create new filenames for each using the primary_key of the user and the report pk as a prefix followed by a datetime stamp to avoid duplicates but its really messy you should really schemigrate to do this properly

Comment: I tried in different method ,getting some error i updated my question in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16625055/nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-user