# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'user'

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-views

models.py

```
class Report(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=False)
    photo_files_attached = models.BooleanField('Photos', default=False)
```

views.py

```
def media(request):
    user = request.user  
    try:

        report = Report.objects.get(user=user.id)
    except:
        report = None

    report_dir = str(report.user.id) + '/' + str(report.id)
    output_dir = settings.MEDIA_ROOT + '/' + report_dir
    imagelist = []
    if os.path.exists(output_dir):
        os.chdir(output_dir)
        for files in os.listdir("."):
            for extension in JPEG_ALLOWED:
                if files.endswith(extension):
                    image_with_path = report_dir + '/' + files
                    imagelist.append(image_with_path)
    return render(request, 'incident/media.html',
                  {
                   'newreport_menu': True,
                   'report':report,

                 })
```

I am trying to upload the image file and save it to database,getting the below error "`'NoneType' object has no attribute 'user'`"

Comment: On a side note while .get(user=user.id) works, `.get(user=user)` is sufficient.

Comment: for my case,it is still giving the same error

Comment: yeah.. i know.. I did not give you a solution. Do one thing - go to the admin interface, add a report for this user if not already present, and execute the code again. It should work. Code looks fine to me

Comment: Yes,i tried the same,still the error is their

Comment: ok.. one more thing. Just remove the try except and see what error you get. My guess is, you might have multiple reports related to the user.

Answer (score 3):

It seems

```
Report.objects.get(user=user.id)
```

Gives you an `EmptyQuerySet`

The user in question probably hasn't got any associated `Report` instances yet.

You could use [get_or_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create)

Comment: Get or create returns 2 params, a created flag and the instance, you'll need to assign the latter. `obj = Report.objects.get_or_create(**kwargs)[0]`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like report is `None` in your code:

```
try:
    report = Report.objects.get(user=user.id)
except:
    report = None # <---- your are most probably here
```

So later `report.user` will raise `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'user'`. Make sure report is not `None` and make appropriate checks.